# Segfault on free()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, free, corruption

I'm having a simple problem: my program segfaults when freeing some memory allocated using calloc(). The last function in the backtrace is _IO_str_pbackfail. Currently I'm using icc version 12.1.6. According to other questions on stack overflow, this I usually caused by heap corruption. By looking at calloc sources, it seems that the function writes some data in the first 16 bytes of the allocated space. I've tried to add a watchpoint on these bytes but the debugger isn't detecting any malicious write. Any ideas on how to track down this issue?

Comment: Use GDB and back-trace (bt). But if you want more help you will have to post your code.

Comment: Please post the smallest version of your code that exhibits the segfault.

Comment: Smells like an aliased/stale pointer.

Comment: You are either multiply freeing or you have overwritten some of the bookkeeping data at some point. Either way you have a serious problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running with [`MALLOC_CHECK_=2`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) or [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Valgrind found the issue. A buffer overflow was overwriting the 16 magic bytes. I still don't understand why watch didn't catch this, though